# Choosing a cost function for optimization

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

Suppose I have an independent variable $x\in[0, 1]$ and a function $f(x):[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ such that

- $f(x) = 1 \Leftrightarrow x = 0$,
- $f(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = 1$, and
- $f$ is a decreasing function of $x$,

and that both $x$ and $f(x)$ need to be as small as possible in some as-yet ill-defined sense.  I could define a cost function, but the most obvious choice, $g(x): = xf(x)$, will not work because it is minimized exactly when one variable is minimized and the other is maximized.  On the other hand, a function like $h(x):=x + f(x)$ could work.

But the bigger problem remains: I only found $h(x)$ by intuition + guess-and-check.  How can I *methodically* come up with a good cost function?  For example, suppose I have one or more of the following additional requirements:

1. the value of $x$ is, in practice, much closer to 1 than to 0;
2. I want to allow, but "penalize," values of $x$ that are too close to 1; or
3. I know that minimizing $f(x)$ is roughly three times as important as minimizing $x$.

Is there some theory on this subject that would be accessible to a math graduate student whose studies have touched very little on optimization?

Comment: It seems to me that you would have to have a specific cost in mind before you can even consider optimizing it (= minimizing the cost). Suppose for example I gave you two values for $x$ that I claim are optimal. How would you choose between them, or verify that they are both optimal? You can't, unless you have a cost in mind whose values you would compare at each of my candidates.

Comment: @MPW I'll think about this a little more.  I suppose my question for now becomes "where do I *start* to find an appropriate cost function," given certain requirements on the values of $x$ and $f(x)$ (especially the third one, where there is a relative priority (albeit a poorly-defined one) for which variable to minimize.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea.

Let's say that all three requirements apply.  Then $-\log(1-x)$ is an increasing function of $x$, and both it and its derivative increase without bound as $x\rightarrow 1^-$.  So it's a sensible preliminary cost function to penalize values of $x$ that are too high.  The same can be said for $f(x)$, so let's set our cost function to be
$C(x) = -\log(1-x) - 3\log(1-f(x))$.  For the moment, think of $f(x)$ as a second independent variable $y$; then $y\rightarrow y + h$ affects the cost function three times as much as $x\rightarrow x + h$.  Thus $C(x)$ is a good start, although now we need to remove the assumption of independence.